# How to make OSX In-app purchase alerts visible in front of full screen window?

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, fullscreen

After making the main window full screen and change the window level:

```
    [fullScreenWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
```

all the In-app purchase alerts are displayed behind, and not visible for user, unless you switch to background or change the window level again to:

```
    [fullScreenWindow setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel];
```

How to make In-app purchase alerts visible in front of full screen window? or if not possible, how to detect that alert is displayed at the moment?